# Boto3 - possible upload generator object to s3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I would like to upload the results of a generator to s3 while fully taking advantage of the generator.

A mve of what I'm trying to do is:

```
def gen():
    for i in ['a','b','c','d']
        yield i

s3_object.put?(data=gen())
```

I've seen examples of putting local filepaths into .put, but havent seen anything regarding generators.
Ideally this would fully take advantage of the generator so I don't have to write all the data to disk or memory.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Can you clarify. Where is `['a','b','c','d']` coming from? If you put it in a function, its no different then using naked for loop.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is currently not possible. According to the [doc](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put), the `Body` parameter only accepts bytes or seekable file-like object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this using a multipart upload. The minimum size for a "part" is 5MiB, so you need to build a buffer that holds the data until 5MiB is reached.

Here is a class that gets the job done:

```py
import boto3


class MultipartUpload:
    def __init__(self, bucket, key, client=None, encoding="utf8"):
        self.bucket = bucket
        self.key = key
        self.client = client or boto3.client("s3")
        self.encoding = encoding
        upload = self.client.create_multipart_upload(
            Bucket=bucket, Key=key
        )
        self.upload_id = upload["UploadId"]
        self.part = 1
        self.parts_container = []
        self.buffer = b''

    def write(self, content):
        if isinstance(content, str):
            self.buffer += content.encode(self.encoding)
        elif isinstance(content, bytes):
            self.buffer += content
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"Received bad data of type {type(content)}. Must be bytes or string")
        if len(self.buffer) > 5 * 1024 * 1024:  # 5 MiB Minimum part upload
            self.commit()

    def commit(self):
        print("Sending multipart")
        resp = self.client.upload_part(
            Body=self.buffer, Bucket=self.bucket, Key=self.key,
            PartNumber=self.part, UploadId=self.upload_id
        )
        self.parts_container.append(
            {"ETag": resp["ETag"], "PartNumber": self.part}
        )
        self.buffer = b''
        self.part += 1

    def save(self):
        if self.buffer:  # If we have leftover data; commit it first
            self.commit()
        return self.client.complete_multipart_upload(
            Bucket=self.bucket, Key=self.key, UploadId=self.upload_id,
            MultipartUpload={"Parts": self.parts_container}
        )

    def abort(self):
        self.client.abort_multipart_upload(
            Bucket=self.bucket, Key=self.key, UploadId=self.upload_id
        )

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type_, value, tb):
        if type_:
            self.abort()
        else:
            self.save()
```

You could of course improve this for things like threading and further optimisation. You would use it like a file handle:

```py
with MultipartUpload("your-bucket", "file.txt") as upload:
    for data in gen():
        upload.write(data)
```